# Why does this JavaScript code make the entire array point to the same object?

Tags: javascript

In the book `Javascript: The Good Parts`, there is this code on page 64:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i += 1) {
 my_array[i] = [];
}
// Note: Array.dim(n, []) will not work here.
// Each element would get a reference to the same
// array, which would be very bad.
```

Why would each element in the array point to the same object? It seems to me that the line `my_array[i] = [];` be reevaluated each loop, causing a new empty object to be created.

What're the rules of getting a reference to the same object versus a new one? How would I make this get a different empty array every loop?

EDIT: Reading people's responses, I just read the paragraph wrong. Thanks for all the answers!

Comment: what is `dim()` method's implemetation

Comment: I think you misinterpreted the comment in the book. They say that `my_array[i] = [];` works and `Array.dim(n, [])` doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This loop does get a new reference each time. Run it, mutate one of the arrays and you'll see that only one changes.

The problem is much more likely to be with the `Array.dim` method. I would imagine that it's implemented something like this:

```
Array.dim = function(n, init) {
  var arr = [];
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < n; i += 1) {
    arr[i] = init;
  }

  return arr;
}
```

Using the literal array syntax create a new reference to an array, but this method uses the *same reference* to populate each value of the resulting array.

It might be easiest to compare the two this way.

```
var init = [];
for (i = 0; i < n; i += 1) {
  arr[i] = init;
}
```

The first approach creates one array then uses it to populate each element.

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i += 1) {
  arr[i] = [];
}
```

The second approach creates a new reference for each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Line "Each element would get a reference to the same" related to Array.dim implementation from page 63:

```
// "Javascript: The Good Parts", page 63.
Array.dim = function (dimension, initial) {
 var a = [], i;
 for (i = 0; i < dimension; i += 1) {
 a[i] = initial;
 }
 return a;
};
```

Code at page 64 gives you an array of different pointers for array.

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i += 1) {
 my_array[i] = [];
}


// you can try to do this:
my_array[0].push(1);
my_array[1].push(2);

console.log(my_array[0]);
// [1]

console.log(my_array[1]);
// [2]
```

Answer (score 1):

The premise of your question is incorrect:

> Why would each element in the array point to the same object?

It doesn't. Each loop populates the ***i*** <sup>th</sup> element of the main array with a new and distinct empty array. [See this jsBin](http://jsbin.com/zudiwamice/edit?js,console,output).

http://jsbin.com/zudiwamice/edit?js,console,output

```
var my_array = [],
    n = 5;
for (i = 0; i < n; i += 1) {
  my_array[i] = [];
}
console.log(my_array); // [[], [], [], [], []]
```